# how do I download just hdfs not hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How do I download just hdfs not hadoop? I am trying to install it on either linux/mac/windows. I tried searching but all the results point to hadoop installer e.g. http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.5.1

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean? HDFS is a part of hadoop. Why you want to download HDFS alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, You can do it.. Hadoop is a collection of jars. So you can download the specific jars as you needed [**HDFS**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.5.2)

But HDFS alone you may be able to perform copy/delete/create operations. Apart from that nothing. The base of Hadoop is HDFS and MapReduce jars which must be used to do simple wordcount example also.
And other stuff like addon jars which enhances the functionalities can be downloaded [**Here**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop)

While creating project, use Maven which takes care of dependent jars. Else it will be terrible to find all the dependent jars.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree with Mr.Chowdhary above. Since Hadoop 0.21 (back in 2010) Hadoop Core has been split between Common, HDFS and MapReduce.

Refer Tom White's excellent article here http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/08/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-apache-hadoop-0-21/

Do note, however, that HDFS will still have dependencies on Hadoop Common which you will need to download as separate jars.